# Unable to send metrics to graphite-exporter

Tags: graphite, prometheus-node-exporter, graphite-carbon

I am trying to send custom metrics to graphite exporter, using nc command, but unsuccessful.
Here is the steps:

- I wget the graphite exporter on my redhat machine using url :
  https://github.com/prometheus/graphite_exporter/releases/download/v0.7.1/graphite_exporter-0.7.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
- unzip the tar and execute in background using command :

  ```
  ./graphite_exporter &
  ```
- Now the graphite exporter listens on ports :

  netstat -ntpl

  tcp6       0      0 :::9108                 :::*                    LISTEN    92554/./graphite_ex

  tcp6       0      0 :::9109                 :::*                    LISTEN      92554/./graphite_ex
- I am following this article (http://graphiteapp.org/quick-start-guides/feeding-metrics.html) to execute below commands with output mentioned:

  ```
         echo "foo.bar 1 `date +%s`" | nc -vz localhost 9108
         Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
         Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:9108.
         Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
  ```
- I am able to telnet on port 9108 :

  ```
         telnet localhost 9108
         Trying 127.0.0.1...
         Connected to localhost.
         Escape character is '^]'.
         ^]
         telnet> quit
         Connection closed.
  ```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong to push the metrics to graphite exporter, Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

u use the wrong port, the webclient uses 9108 but metrics will be only accepted at 9109, like it is described in the README https://github.com/prometheus/graphite_exporter